# Is app-id in private alpha public

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I have an app that I have published in alpha mode through Google Play. The app is in stealth mode and so I want the name/id of the app to remain private. But the url from google is `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompany.myapp`. So I am wondering if some unsanctioned person may discover my app id/name.

Comment: Can you see it in the store if you sign out?

Comment: I do a number of testing, all satisfactory. But as those things go all I need is a counter-example. So I was wondering if there is a doc somewhere that lay this to rest.

Answer (score 0):

From [Google Play Support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en):

> Alpha- or beta-test apps will only appear in Google Play for testers that opt-in and not to any other users.

If you've done testing yourself and just want some documentation backing it up, you can't get much better than that.